# Type error for merge() function in Keras for 2d convolutional layer

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to recreate the Inception model version 4. But i want to train it on my image data set standard shape `(224,224,3)` ,so i am not taking in any pretrained weights.
But I am getting an error like this.

```
x = merge([x1, x2], mode='concat', concat_axis=channel_axis)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Here is the code:

```
def inception_stem(input):
    if K.image_dim_ordering() == "th":
        channel_axis = 1
    else:
        channel_axis = -1

    # Input Shape is 299 x 299 x 3 (th) or 3 x 299 x 299 (th)
    x = conv_block(input, 32, 3, 3, subsample=(2, 2), border_mode='valid')
    x = conv_block(x, 32, 3, 3, border_mode='valid')
    x = conv_block(x, 64, 3, 3)

    x1 = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), border_mode='valid')(x)
    x2 = conv_block(x, 96, 3, 3, subsample=(2, 2), border_mode='valid')
    x = tf.concat([x1,x2],axis=channel_axis)
    #x = merge([x1, x2], mode='concat', concat_axis=channel_axis) #here is the error occuring try find out the reason behind it

    x1 = conv_block(x, 64, 1, 1)
    x1 = conv_block(x1, 96, 3, 3, border_mode='valid')

    x2 = conv_block(x, 64, 1, 1)
    x2 = conv_block(x2, 64, 1, 7)
    x2 = conv_block(x2, 64, 7, 1)
    x2 = conv_block(x2, 96, 3, 3, border_mode='valid')

    x = merge([x1, x2], mode='concat', concat_axis=channel_axis)

    x1 = conv_block(x, 192, 3, 3, subsample=(2, 2), border_mode='valid')
    x2 = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), border_mode='valid')(x)

    x = merge([x1, x2], mode='concat', concat_axis=channel_axis)
    return x
```

I am using `python 3.6`,`keras 2.2.2` , `tensorflow-gpu 1.9.0`.

*I followed the GitHub for the issue, but the answers were not clear and exact.*
Can anyone find the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the concatenate layer, that should help you

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import concatenate
x = concatenate([x1, x2], axis=channel_axis)
return x
```

Comment: i tried this but i am getting an errror like this after using the concatenate. method.'Got inputs shapes: %s' % (input_shape))
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 74, 74, 64), (None, 75, 75, 96)]

Comment: Yeah you need to compulsory have tensors of same dimension in all axes but for the concat axis. In your case it should either be [(None, 74, 74, 64), (None, 74, 74, 96)] or [(None, 75, 75, 64), (None, 75, 75, 96)]. I suggest you to check the shapes of previous layers

Comment: well in the conventional inception model v4 they are using no padding, so when i concat the two layers it will have different dimensions.So i used padding equal to same to overcome this issue.Is there a way i can concatenate layers with two different shapes without using padding.

Comment: You can add padding to get them to same shape, but  concatenate layer would never work with different  shapes in axes other than the concat axis

Comment: Thank you for the insights. I ll consider this as the answer and close this issue.